# How to get adjacent col value in a div-table using js?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an `html` table, which is structured like this:

```
<body>
<div class="block div-table" id="sidebar-record-block">
<div class="div-table-row">
  <div class="div-table-header">Sel</div>
  <div class="div-table-header">Color</div>
  <div class="div-table-header">Hex</div>
</div>
<div id="field-0000" class="div-table-row">
  <input type="checkbox" class="div-table-td" name="checkBox" id="cbfield-0000">
  <div class="div-table-td">yellow</div>
  <div class="div-table-td"></div>
</div>
  <div id="field-0001" class="div-table-row">
    <input type="checkbox" class="div-table-td" name="checkBox" id="cbfield-0001">
    <div class="div-table-td">red</div>
  <div class="div-table-td"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I can iterate over the checkboxes using the code below and push the checked rows into an array:

```
saveButton.onclick = function(){
   var checkedRowIndexes = []; 
  var selectedColors = []; 
  var checkedRows = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++){
    if (checkedRows[i].checked){
    checkedRowIndexes.push(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(checkedRowIndexes);
}
```

But how would I go about iterating over the `table` and push the color (2º col) instead, using `javascript`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var checkedRowIndexes = [];
var selectedColors = [];
var checkedRows = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++) {
  if (checkedRows[i].checked) {    
    checkedRowIndexes.push(i);
    selectedColors.push(checkedRows[i].nextElementSibling.innerText);
  }
}
console.log(checkedRowIndexes, selectedColors);
```

```html
<div class="block div-table" id="sidebar-record-block">
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-header">Sel</div>
    <div class="div-table-header">Color</div>
    <div class="div-table-header">Hex</div>
  </div>
  <div id="field-0000" class="div-table-row">
    <input type="checkbox" class="div-table-td" name="checkBox" id="cbfield-0000">
    <div class="div-table-td">yellow</div>
    <div class="div-table-td"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="field-0001" class="div-table-row">
    <input type="checkbox" class="div-table-td" name="checkBox" id="cbfield-0001">
    <div class="div-table-td">red</div>
    <div class="div-table-td"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as the end of the question states, how would we get the color instead of the index. I suppose that this would be a nested ```for loop```? Appreciate your time.

Comment: right, you want to get color value, if the checkbox is checked. try the updated code

Comment: Awesome! I had in my mind it was close, but getting here has filled my head with so much, I can't get enough for today. Thank you!